# WP_Query: offset ignored when posts_per_page is -1?

Tags: posts, wp-query, offsets

Is it only me or this is what's happening?

I just want to get all posts starting from a certain offset, like 10. Instead I get all posts starting from the 0.

Comment: Same behvaior here. Havn't found any notice about in the codex so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`posts_per_page => -1` is equivalent to `'nopaging' => true`, which basically means no LIMIT clause is used at all.

The workaround is to set posts_per_page to a large number.

This is a limitation of the LIMIT syntax itself:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: ok, I'll just substract my offset from found_posts from the previous query and pass it as post_per_page in the next one